# Taylor series expansion of analytic functions on domain $D$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, cauchy-integral-formula

Regarding the Taylor series expansion of an analytic function, analytic functions are defined on the largest disc in side domain $D$, and is derived using the Cauchy Integral formula. Is there any specific reason to bound that expansion within a disc? I mean to say, Cauchy's Integral formula, can in general be applied on any weird shapes inside the domain, why not use that? We just need to make sure, it stays inside the radius of convergence. Please someone clarify.

Comment: The power series for $\frac 1 {1+z^{2}}$ is valid only for $|z|<1$ even though the function is analytic in the bigger region $\{z: |\Im (z) |<1\}$.

Comment: I guess that is because $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ has its radius of convergence, $|z|<1$, right? What if, the domain $D$ is a subset of the radius of convergence?

Comment: The power seriss converges inside the disk of radius $R$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence. If the domain is contained in this disk of course, the series conveges in the domain .

Comment: So, it is not necessary that the expansion is done inside a disk of radius $r<R$. it can be inside any arbitrary domain as long as that domain is a subset of $R$ radius disk? My instructor is always taking a disk, so that is why I am asking

Comment: Disks have specific analytic and geometric properties that other domains do not have (for example one knows all their holomorphic automorphisms, the poisson kernel has a very nice expression etc, plus good geometric properties like convexity) and they form a topological basis of any open set so many times it is enough to use only them

Comment: Thanks for your help @Conrad